# Visualizing Clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical

I have done cluster analysis using `hclust()`, and now I wish to plot those clusters on to a map. X and Y coordinates of data are available. Finally I have x,y coordinate of the data point, and I have the specific number(cluster to which the data belongs) that must be visible at that specific point. I have plotted Dendrogram already but I wish to plot points using x,y coordinates available.

Suppose a data belongs to the group: 1 and it's coordinates are x1 and y1, I wish to mark/label the point as 1 showing that this specific point belongs to cluster: 1.

Please tell me how to do so, if any better representation of clusters on maps is also available, please tell me about it too.

I am really new to R.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest coloring each point as the cluster. I am particularly fond of the beautiful graphics in `ggplot2` one of the more popular graphics packages.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat<-data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), cluster=rep(c("a","b"),5))
qplot(x=x,y=y,data=dat,color=cluster)
```

[image]

You can do something similar with base R graphics, but the resulting graph is much less attractive IMO. You could certainly "beautify" it, but the simplicity of 1 liner in `ggplot2` and the beauty of the output seem to make more sense to me, from a return on code perspective.

```
plot(x=dat$x, y=dat$y,col=dat$cluster)
legend("topleft",c("a","b"),cex=1,text.col=c("black","red"),bty="n")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but can I do it without using any external library if possible ?

Comment: is this what you were looking for?